# Rails insert each line from a text_area in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms

In my rails app I have a text_field, which inserts a string value into the db after a button is pushed. But I would like to replace that text_field with a text_area and insert every line as a new record into my DB. I am using simple_form.

```
_form
<%= simple_form_for @keyword do |f|%>
<%=f.input :name%>
<%=f.button :submit%>
<%end%>

controller
@keyword = Keyword.new(keyword_params)
 if @keyword.save
 redirect_to :back
end
```

I almost know what I have to do, but where do I have to parse the list into the controller or model?

Thank you.

Comment: show your code, please

Answer (score 1):

Line breaks are represented by `\n` on your string. Knowing this, on your controller you can get the text_area parameter, something like `params[:text_area]` and use the `String#split` method to convert this String into an array of n positions, based on the number of line breaks.

```
string_array = params[:text_area].split("\n")
# do your stuff with the array of strings
```

Comment: Yep, that's the idea. Or maybe setting them in variables like `value = string_array[0]`, `value = string_array[1]`, etc. But this way you have to know how many strings you will always have.

Comment: In my create method, how do I get the params, I added your code and I get the error message that split method unknown, because I don't get any params. What I did was adding your line, and after that do a each loop and take each line from the text field and add it into a variable and save it.

Comment: Well, you have to change the `:text_area` to your actual value on your form.

Comment: I did that:)) and I added a logger to see if I get something from params, and I do. but when I add the split method it gives me that error. split method undefined

Answer (score 0):

To solve that problem I did this:

```
 keyword_array = keyword_params[:name].split("\r\n")

 def keyword_params
    params.require(:keyword).permit(:name)
 end
```